# Add images into rails article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, blogs, gif

With Rails 5.1 and a pgsql database: I have a pretty standard Article model with :title and :description. Users can make your typical text-only articles.

What if users wanted to embed a gif or image into the post, like between paragraphs? I see a lot of this type of format on other website blogs and I am not sure how to achieve this with Rails.

Note also I am using simple_format(article) to display, so any formatting done on creation should hold.

Any ideas?

Comment: For that you can use any rich text editor .

Comment: You might want to start looking here https://www.tiny.cloud/ or https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

Comment: You can certainly use paperclip to attach images to Article model. But need to make sure position of it remains same. Or [https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails] editor is good.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually quite a bit of work involved with this:

1. If you need to allow your users to upload images from their
   computer, you will need to get your head around the [Paperclip
   gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (or similar). This will store the image on the server.
   You'll want to determine how big can images be, what to name the
   images once uploaded and what file formats are permitted to prevent
   users uploading all sorts of files.
2. Next on the front-end, you can either use a rich text editor (eg. [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) are the main ones) to embed the
   IMG tag(s) into your Article text, or structure that layout yourself
   (eg. "Always display an image before/after the article text"). Do
   your images need captions? Do they need to be clickable?
3. Lastly, in your Show template, don't forget to use [Rail's image tag helpers](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) rather than your standard IMG tags. This enables you
   to easily reference the images on the server without getting lost in
   the asset pipeline.

There are some videos out there showing how all this is done, eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5W-Y3aROVE. Good luck!